# href in jquery for jvector map

Tags: jquery, href

Hi actually i try to do a function which will redirect me on a another page with a link in jquery function but i'm a litle bit lost in the syntaxe and that doesn't work can you help me please ? :)

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
     map: 'world_en',
     backgroundColor: '#333333',
     color: '#ffffff',
     hoverOpacity: 0.7,
     selectedColor: '#666666',
     enableZoom: true,
     showTooltip: true,
     scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#006491'],
     values: sample_data,
     normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
     });
    jQuery('#vmap').click(function(){
       $('#vmap').attr('<a href = ',"<?php echo $valeur->id ?>><?php echo $valeur->Name; ?></a>")    
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return false` to prevent the default action of clicking on URL (assuming that `#vmap` is an `a` tag).

Additionally, you had some syntax errors in your concatenation (with the single and double quotes).

You'll want to manipulate the `href` attribute separately from its inner text.

```
jQuery('#vmap').click(function(){
  $('#vmap').attr("href", "<?php echo $valeur->id ?>").text("<?php echo $valeur->Name; ?>");
  return false;
 });
```

Comment: thank you so much that work but i think i must try another way to get the name of the country selected for the good redirection beceause actualy that return a black page :/.Do you have some idea ?